# AngularJS/Parse $http --data-urlencode

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, angularjs

I need to retrieve a specific data using AngularJS's $http calling Parse RESTFUL API, the only way Parse allows me to do it is to send in a "--data-urlencode where={"storeId":2}" into a curl call.

`curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:ApplicationId" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ApiKey" -G --data-urlencode 'where={"storeId":2}' https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Stores/`

see here: https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-arrays

I'm able to return a JSON result using the terminal but not with $http(). Anyone know how i can inject "--data-urlencode where={"storeId":2}" into the AngularJS $http() or $resource() methods?

see here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking a the python reference of the parse api, I guess the `where={"storeId":2}` can be appended as a query parameter (I cannot test this without access to the parse api). From the reference:

```py
params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
   "arrayKey": 2
})})
```

In AngularJS you can add query parameters with the `param` key in `$http`'s `config` object:

```js
var req = $http({
    params: {
        where: {storeId: 2},
    },
    headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'ApplicationID',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'ApiKey'
    }
    //... other params, like URL
});
```

The `params.where` value will be turned into a JSON string automatically. I am not sure if the query parameters get URL encoded by default, if not, JSON encode them manually and apply the `encodeURIComponent` function.